# Angular UI Router: How do I get parent view to be "active" when navigating to nested view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm working on a project that has implemented the UI router and it's using `ui-sref-active="active"` to add the active class to the navigation menu item when that item is the current route. However, when you navigate to a nested view within that view, the parent menu item is no longer active. See the following Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2CoEdS?p=preview

By default (or if you click on it) Route 1 is "active". When you click on "Show List," you will see that Route 1 is no longer active.

**Edit:**

The only difference between this example and my actual project is that the navigation menu in my actual project has its own controller and so does not use the same scope as the controller for "route1".

Comment: This question is 2 years old, there's plenty of answers, and the API has changed drastically since I first posted this, so please, don't waste your time.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**EDIT For updated ui-router 0.2.13:**

`ui-sref-active="active"` now sets the 'active' class when the current state is the ui-sref's state **or any child**

`ui-sref-active-eq="active"` behaves as the previous iterations of ui-sref-active, and only sets the class for the exact state

**Original Answer:**

See open ui-router issues: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/704 and [818](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/818)

A general workaround people are suggesting is:

```
ng-class="{active:$state.includes('route1')}"
```

Of course, $state must be added to $scope.  See updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/KHLDJP?p=preview

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/927 was merged to master.  Apparently it didn't make it into the 0.2.10 release, but should be available in the next release, likely 0.2.11.

Comment: ui-router now supports this natively: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/bf163ad6ce176ce28792696c8302d7cdf5c05a01

Comment: You can also use it as a filter like this:  `ng-class="{active: ('route1' | includedByState)}"` which translates to `ng-class="{active:$state.includes('route1')}"`

Comment: Of course, if things get really tricky, you can always just explicitly match the route like this: `ng-class="{active:$state.current.name == 'myRoute'}"`

Answer (score 8):

You are having a wrong understanding of ui-sref-active="active"

```
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a></li>
```

This will show special css highlighting only when you are in state route1 (reference https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#wiki-ui-sref-active). This is the case when you click on route 1. But when you click on "Show list" you are no longer in route1.
Rather you are in state "route1.list" . You can verify this by writing the following code. This is strictly for understanding how state works.

js

inside controller

```
$rootScope.currentState = $state.$current.name //using rootScope so that you can access the variable anywhere inside html
```

inside html

```
{{currentState}}
```

If you look closely at documentation of ui-sref-active, it not only looks at stateName but also stateParams, hence when you go to substate it no longer changes css. From the sourcecode it becomes clearer.

```
 function update() {
        if ($state.$current.self === state && matchesParams()) {
          $element.addClass(activeClass);
        } else {
          $element.removeClass(activeClass);
        }// route1===route1.list will not be true.
```

to solve the problem, remember scope variables are inherited in nested views.

inside controller of route.

```
$scope.route1Active = true;
```

in html

```
<li ng-class={active:route1Active}><a ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a></li>
```

Comment: I understand how ui-sref-active="active" works. I am simply looking for solutions to what I see as a common problem that ui-sref-active doesn't address. Thank you, your solution works, but not with my projects particular set up (see edit above). Also, I prefer not to add to $rootScope if something can be better scoped elsewhere.

Comment: i think you can file it as an issue with angular ui-router team and see how it goes

Answer (score 5):

Angular UI router now supports this natively. See commit https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/bf163ad6ce176ce28792696c8302d7cdf5c05a01

Answer (score 4):

My solution was to set:

```
<li ng-class="{ 'active': state.current.name.indexOf('route1') != -1 }">
```

The state was already previously added to the controller's scope:

```
$scope.state = $state;
```

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. Thats official code: ng-class="{active:$state.includes('route1')}"

Comment: `$state.includes` does not work for nested views. It wont work for `route1.nested`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do any thing in the controllers. Here is my example code:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="tablist">
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="Booking.Step1" href="#/Booking/Step1">Step1</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="Booking.Step2" href="#/Booking/Step2" >Step2</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="Booking.Step3" href="#/Booking/Step3">Step3</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="Booking.Step4" href="#/Booking/Step4">Step4</a></li>
        <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="Booking.Step5" href="#/Booking/Step5">Step5</a></li>
    </ul>
```

In route configuration:

```
$stateProvider.state('Booking', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/Booking',
        templateUrl: "TourApp/Templates/Booking/SideMenu.html",
        controller: "SideMenuController"
    });

    $stateProvider.state('Booking.Step1', {
        url: "/Step1",
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: "TourApp/Templates/Booking/Step1.html",
                controller: "Step1Controller"
            }
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state('Booking.Step2', {
        url: "/Step2",
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: "TourApp/Templates/Booking/Step2.html",
                controller: "Step2Controller"
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Now they have updated and the new way to do that is

```
 <a ui-sref-active="{'active': 'main.app.manage.**'}" ui-sref="main.app.manage.people.list"></a>
```

Below is the state file

```
 angular.module('manage.people', ['people.invite'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('main.app.manage.people', {
        url: '/people',
        abstract: true,
        cache: false,
        views: {
          'tabContent': {
            template: '<div ui-view="peopleContent"></div>',
            controller: 'peopleController'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('main.app.manage.people.list', {
        url: '/list',
        views: {
          'peopleContent': {
            templateUrl: '/internal/main/app/manage/people/views/people.html',
            controller: 'peopleListController'
          }
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

We already have a solution without any "hack" [HERE](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/bf163ad6ce176ce28792696c8302d7cdf5c05a01)

That's the way to do:

HTML >

```
 <li ui-sref-active="active" >
   <a href="#" class="submenu" ui-sref="bands">
       <i class="fa fa-location-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     Bands
           <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
   </a>

   <ul class="nav child_menu">
        <li ui-sref-active="active">
            <a  ui-sref="bands.nirvana">
                 Nirvana   
            </a>
       </li>
       <li ui-sref-active="active">
            <a  ui-sref="bands.iron">
                Iron
            </a>
       </li>
       <li ui-sref-active="active">
            <a  ui-sref="bands.metalica">
                Metalica
            </a>
       </li>           
  </ul>
```

Our router config will be like this >

```
$stateProvider.state('bands', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/bands',
    templateUrl: "myapp/categories/template.bands.html", //<ui-view></ui-view> 
    controller: "SomeController as vm"
}).state('bands.nirvana', {
    url: '/nirvana',
    templateUrl: "myapp/categories/band.nirvana.html",
    controller: "SomeController as vm"
}).state('bands.iron', {
    url: '/iron',
    templateUrl: "myapp/categories/band.iron.html",
    controller: "SomeController as vm"
}).state('bands.meatlica', {
    url: '/metalica',
    templateUrl: "myapp/categories/band.metalica.html",
    controller: "SomeController as vm"
})
```

Comment: at last it works, and this is great! But when I click on the link to open the sub menu I get the error: Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'bands'(…)"

Answer (score 1):

I have come here 2 years later the question was asked but `angular-ui-router` has much proficient approach in solving this issue. It worked for nested states too.

```
<ul>
  <li ui-sref-active="active" class="item">
    <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

When app navigates to `home` state, this is how resulting HTML will appear :

```
<ul>
  <li ui-sref-active="active" class="item active">
    <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

> ui-sref-active quick reference :
>
> A directive working alongside ui-sref to add classes to an element
>   when the related ui-sref directive's state is active, and removing
>   them when it is inactive. The primary use-case is to simplify the
>   special appearance of navigation menus relying on ui-sref, by having
>   the "active" state's menu button appear different, distinguishing it
>   from the inactive menu items.

[Complete documentation.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref-active)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you have been looking for.Place the parent url in the list class ,now whenever you navigate to child class parent class will be active

Step 1: Add a Controller for your nav bar orin your existing controller where nav bar is included add the following

```
app.controller('navCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
        $scope.isActive = function(destination) {
        return destination === $location.path();
    }

}]);
```

Step2: In your nav bar

```
<li ng-class="{active: isActive('/home')}"><a ui-sref="app.home">Browse Journal</a></li>
```

Thats it.