# ui-router active class for parent menu when submenu selected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am a newbie to ui-router , i would like to get a menu like below (its not a collapse thing, please see the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1kpmUiacrb3Aoo4E19O1?p=preview) )

1. menu1

   a) submenu1

   b) submenu2

   c) submenu3
2. menu2
3. menu3

I managed to get the menus and submenus using the ui-router but not sure about  the proper way to use the ui-router and used `ui-sref-active="active"` active the menu , the problem am facing is when I click on the submenu i would like to get the active to parent also.. ie if I click `submenu1` , `submenu2` or `submneu3` i want to active its parent `menu1`.

here is the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/1kpmUiacrb3Aoo4E19O1?p=preview

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054391/angular-ui-router-how-do-i-get-parent-view-to-be-active-when-navigating-to-ne

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HpVUvqz84uAurpbAPdTd?p=preview), which does use the `$state.includes` method as defined here

- [Angular UI Router: How do I get parent view to be "active" when navigating to nested view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054391)

the changes are: menu gets controller which puts `$state` into `$scope`:

```
"menu@dashboard": { templateUrl: "menu.html", 
            controller : function ($scope, $state){ $scope.$state = $state },
      },
```

instead of this:

```
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".menu1.submenu1">Menu 1</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref=".menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
```

we have to use defintion with `ng-class`:

```
<li ng-class="{active:$state.includes('dashboard.menu1')}"><a ui-sref=".menu1.submenu1">Menu 1</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active:$state.includes('dashboard.menu2')}"><a ui-sref=".menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active:$state.includes('dashboard.menu3')}"><a ui-sref=".menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
```

BUT: this feature would be in a next `ui-router` release as we can see here:

- [feat(uiSrefActive): Also activate for child states.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/bf163ad6ce176ce28792696c8302d7cdf5c05a01)

*cite*

> To limit activation to target state use new `ui-sref-active-eq` directive
>
> Breaking Change: Since ui-sref-active now activates even when child states are active you may need to swap out your ui-sref-active with ui-sref-active-eq, thought typically we think devs want the auto inheritance.