# AngularJS: Change CSS by clicking another button

Tags: css, angularjs

I have 3 buttons "Home","About" and "Contact". On page load I want only the "Home" button to be active. After clicking the "About" button, only the "About" button should be active and the rest 2 buttons not active. Similarly, after clicking the "Contact" button, only the "Contact" button should be active and the rest 2 buttons not active.

The word "active" here means that the button having different CSS (when compared to the other 2 buttons). I am using AngularJS as my front-end JS.[image]

Comment: What routing are you using?

Comment: @krutkowski86 angular ui router

Comment: Please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219315/angular-ui-router-ui-sref-active-and-nested-states), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275348/active-link-tab-in-angularui-router) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054391/angular-ui-router-how-do-i-get-parent-view-to-be-active-when-navigating-to-ne) to get more examples

Answer (score 3):

You will want to read up on the documentation for the Angular [ngClass directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

With `ngClass` you can bind a css class to a variable in your view.

Assuming you set the `page` on your `$scope`.

JS (inside your angular controller)

```
$scope.page = 'home';
```

HTML

```
<li ng-class="{'active': page == 'home'}" ng-click="page = 'home'">Home</li>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .active {
        background: blue;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ui-router then there's a directive called ui-sref-active which adds custom class when particular state is active.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/irhabi/x4uuuxjr/) which shows how it works. Point `student.profile` state which adds `active` class also on `student` state.